# How to total the time in all records using MySQL

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have this record:

```
ot_id    overtime
1        02:30
2        01:00
```

In MySql, how can I select the total number of overtime (`hours:minutes`)?

Is there any available function in MySQL to sum the total number of hours?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the column's data type?

Comment: Have you considered storing it instead as an integer of minutes, or a decimal of hours?

Comment: Jon Lin: the datatype is time
cosiKa: Actually I can process the computation of time in PHP, I just want to know if there is a function in mysql that can do this.

Comment: @Rafael Won't `time` overflow after about 850 hours though?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
SELECT  
  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `overtime` ) ) ) AS totals  
FROM your_tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `overtime` ) ) ) AS total_time  
FROM time_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that...

I have a table 'table1'
With two columns 'col1' of type 'int'
and 'col2' of type 'time'

To create that table use following script

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `col1` INT(10) NULL,
    `col2` TIME NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

To get total time of second column(col2) use following query

```
SELECT Sec_to_Time(Sum(Time_to_Sec(col2))) FROM table1
```